# Working with types in binary files

Tags: file-io, casting, binary, types

i am currently learning binary file writing again and I have a basic question concerning the types and the data they hold.
I am working through a document describing a binary file. In the header several uint8 datatypes are used but the data that is written in this type is not an integer but a character ("F"). I suppose that I have to cast the char "F" to an unsinged integer, and write that to the file:

```
unsigned int var1 = (int)"F";
fwrite(var1, sizeof(var1), 1, *fp);
```

When opening the resulting file in a hex editor I see that this has not worked, because the letter "F" should be recognized by the editor.
How do I correctly write this to a file?

Thank you very much.

Draetsch

Answer (score 0, accepted):

int is not the same as an int8, an "int" has 32 bits while an int8 has, well, 8 bits. I think the datatype you're looking for here to hold the data from your file in the runtime is an unsigned char, not an unsigned int.

Comment: Hi Delta,thanks for the tip with the bits. I will take a look at that. In the meantime I discovered, that the strings are encoded in UTF-8 which makes them integers, I suppose. I will take a look at encoding right now. Thankls for helping me out.